# No 5Ghz detected and wifi connection "expires" but keeping a terminal pinging an address keeps the connection alive

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

My problem is two-fold, and I think they might be related:

1. On the "select network" tab, I only see 2.4Ghz networks, however my router has the typical 2.4 and 5ghz variant. I much prefer the 5.0 but the only way to connect to it is using `nmcli c up WiFi-5.0-6740`
2. Both connections expire after some minutes, in the sense that its still connected but no internet. However, I found out that keeping a terminal constantly pinging `ping 8.8.8.8` somehow keeps the connection alive.

I have no idea how to tackle the problem, i have reinstall network manager, changed DNS resolving, checked for outdated drivers etc. This happened overnight with no major changes to anything related to network.

I am using ubuntu 22.04.